# C# dynamic parameters in SQL Server query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a problem with calling by SQL Server database. I have this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/537Rb.png)
and an object with property `Groups`, which is something like "all nj sk2".

My query in ssms is

```
SELECT * 
FROM Hours 
WHERE class_id = 1 
  AND groups IN ('all', 'nj', 'sk2')
```

In C# I'm doing something like this

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM Hours WHERE class_id = @class_id AND groups LIKE (@groups)";

using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class_id", User.Current.ClassId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groups", User.Current.Groups.Replace(" ", ", "));
}
```

The only way I made this work was

```
var groups = "('" + User.Current.Groups.Replace(" ", "', '").Remove(User.Current.Groups.Length - 2);
//above is ('all', 'nj', 'sk2')
var query = "SELECT * FROM Hours WHERE class_id = @class_id AND groups LIKE " + groups;

using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class_id", User.Current.ClassId);
}
```

But this is not a good solution imo, so if anyone knows what am I doing wrong please help me out. Thanks

Comment: **[Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)**

Comment: The issue is that the parameter `@groups` represents a single value. That is the benefit of parameters, otherwise SQL injection could occur. (What if `@groups` was `"''); drop table Hours; --"`?)

Comment: This is good thanks @lad2025, but i think i'll still need to use IN statement for further purposes so if anyone has a cooler solution, ill appreciate it

Comment: @HABO I know thats why im asking

Comment: I've closed your question with three duplicates. If that's not enough, you can also use a table valued parameter (that might be just an overkill for such a purpose).